# Why displayed value of b , c and y is different from my trace?

Tags: c++, variables, runtime-error, operators

please tell me why the value of the variable "y" is displayed as '5' although we assign the value 0 to it.
and please let me know whats wrong with my algorithmic trace which led me to the wrong values of b = 1 and c = 1;
thanks all

[image]

```
cout << boolalpha; // Outputs boolean values
// as true or false
   bool res = false;
   int y = 5;
   res = 7 || (y = 0);
   cout << "Result of (7 || (y = 0)): " << res
       << endl;
   cout << "Value of y: " << y << endl;
   int  a, b, c;
   a = b = c = 0;
   res = ++a || ++b && ++c;
   cout << '\n'
       << "  res = " << res
       << ",   a = " << a
       << ",   b = " << b
       << ",   c = " << c << endl ;
   a = b = c = 0;
   res = ++a && ++b || ++c;
   cout << "  res = " << res
       << ",   a = " << a
       << ",   b = " << b
       << ",   c = " << c << endl ;
```

Comment: Why do you think that `res = 7 || (y = 0);` would assign `0`  to `y`?  The right-hand side of the `||` would never be executed because of `7`.

Comment: To add to what @t.niese said, this is commonly called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). There are a few questions/answers already on SO that addresses this.

Comment: i was fooled by the assigning operator on the left which i have always thought it is  always evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference.com - Logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical):

> **Builtin operators** `&&` and `||` perform short-circuit evaluation (**do not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating the first**), but overloaded operators behave like regular function calls and always evaluate both operands

So for `res = 7 || (y = 0)` where `||` is a builtin operator, the result of `7 || (y = 0)` is known after `7` is evaluated and because of that `(y = 0)` won't be evaluated.